# Two threads, one shared attribute. Reader/Writer dilemma

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I have simple problem but still can't find the proper solution (C#)

1. Say I have main thread running in main class that uses certain resource `char[] arena_snapshot` from time to time (parses it, update the arena based on this).
2. Besides, I started worker thread that keeps updating the shared resource `char[] arena_snapshot`.

Is there a chance that in the middle of parsing the worker thread modifies the buffer, so that the main thread parses the buffer incorrectly. **And how do I lock the arena_snapshot while being parsed?**

```
class Arena
{
    List<PLayer> players;
    ...
    public int main()
    {
        arenaClient = new ArenaClient();
        Thread arenaListener = new Thread(new ThreadStart(arenaClient.StartListener));
        arenaListener.IsBackground = true;
        arenaListener.Start(); //Start UDP worker
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        //Let's parse the buffer and update our Arena ..
        ...
        foreach (Player p in players)
        {

            play.Position.X = arenaClient.arena_snapshot[2];
            //etc...
        }

    }
}

class ArenaClient
{
    ...
    public char[] arena_snapshot; //hold most recent information about our Arena (snapshot)
    ...
    public void StartListener()
    {
        while(!done)
        {
            ...
            //Warning! Updating the snapshot, warn the main thread! Don't do this during parsing of the snapshot!
            arena_snapshot = UDPClient.Receive(ref groupEP);;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx)?

```
    private Object thisLock = new Object();
    private char[] _arena_snapshot;
    public char[] arena_snapshot
    {
        get
        {
            lock (thisLock)
            {
                return _arena_snapshot;
            }
        }

        set
        {
            lock (thisLock)
            {
                _arena_snapshot = value;
            }
        }
    }
```